# Ext.form.field.Date Localization

Tags: extjs

I need to change all the strings in the Ext.js datepicker - Ext.form.field.Date to different languages - months names, tooltips, "Today", etc.
In their docs I can see only oprions to change to error messages, nothing more.
Does anyone know any how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way to do that - adding a L11N file:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/localization